# How do I remove a particular color from a picture and set that color from the picture to transparent in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

[Image for numbers[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B8vn.jpg)

Just like in the image link above I have number 1 and I want to remove the white colour from it. I don't have photoshop but if it can be done in pygame then please suggest a method or function, how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function set_colorkey() for instance if you have defined WHITE as being say (255, 255, 255) after you create a surface.

so

```
def drawImage(self):
        sheep_surface = pygame.Surface((self.radius*2,self.radius*2))
        sheep_surface.fill(WHITE)
        sheep_surface.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(sheep_surface, self.color, [self.radius, self.radius], self.radius)
        return sheep_surface.convert()
```

when blitting your image onto a surface. This removes the colour white from your image when you later blit it onto the actual game surface

Comment: I already tried doing this with set_colorkey() it doesn't do anything at all, neither works nor shows error I wanted to ask is there any method other than set_colorkey() which can help

Comment: I doubt so. set_colourkey() is one of the most efficient ways to solve this issue (although you could always go online and find an online editing tool).